# Event for input updated by JQuery calendar

Tags: jquery, events

Which event is triggered when an input value is update by Jquery calendar?

```
        <div class='p2_field'>
        <input type="date" class="mainform_textinputs" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="<?php echo $strSicknessEndDate ?>" />
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Calendar.setup({
                inputField     :    "enddate",
                ifFormat       :    "%d/%m/%Y",
                button         :    "enddate",
                align          :    "Tl",
                singleClick    :    true
            });
        </script>
```

I've tried Change and it does nothing

```
$('.p2_field input').change(function() {
```

and blur is only triggered when the input loses focus

```
$('.p2_field input').blur(function() {
```

Comment: What Calendar library are you using?

Comment: The info in calendar.js says $Id: calendar.js,v 1.53 2006/02/11 12:32:59 mishoo Exp $

Comment: Hmm, I found an old calendar library with that line in it.  But, it doesn't have a setup method, so I don't think it's the right one.  Sorry. Do you know where you got the file from?

Comment: There's a separate calendar-setup.js. The website is: http://dynarch.com/jscal/

Answer (score 0):

There is `onSelect` handler, try:

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField     :    "enddate",
    ifFormat       :    "%d/%m/%Y",
    button         :    "enddate",
    align          :    "Tl",
    singleClick    :    true,
    onSelect       :    function () { console.log('Ping!'); }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any error in console? Are you using both calendar.js and calendar-setup.js?